# ng-click toggle only works on first click

Tags: angularjs, toggle

I want to toggle a boolean by click event using Angular. 
This is my the code

```
<div class="nav_mobile" ng-click="mobilestatus.navActive = (mobilestatus.navActive == false) ? true : false">
    <a href="" class="gradient-menu"></a>
</div>

<nav>
    <ul class="nav_mobile_list" ng-class="{active: mobilestatus.navActive}">
        <li><a ui-sref="about" ng-click="mobilestatus.navActive = false">About</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="contact" ng-click="mobilestatus.navActive = false">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The controller looks like this

```
angular.module('app').controller('NavCtrl', function ($scope){
   $scope.mobilestatus = {navActive: false};
});
```

I also tried other shorthand notations. The initial value of `navActive` is false. The `ng-click` on `nav_mobile` makes the `navActive` attribute true the first time, but when clicking again, it doesn't return back to false. When clicking on the `li` items, the `navActive` does return back to false. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this statement

```
ng-click="mobilestatus.navActive = !mobilestatus.navActive"
```

**EDIT**

If you have no idea of whats going on inside your code try to debug it. Use function call instead of angular's DOM expression and log output into console. Also you can use breakpoints.

HTML

```
ng-click="toggle()"
```

Controller

```
$scope.toggle = function toggle() { 
    $scope.mobilestatus.navActive = !$scope.mobilestatus.navActive;  

    console.log('Status is ' + $scope.mobilestatus.navActive); 
};
```

You will see if this code is executable and $scope.mobilestatus is available to html part.

**EDIT**

Here is [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rZ19CZ4u5EONsmmwI9q2)

Comment: Tried, doesn't work. I guess the problem is elsewhere?

Comment: should work. may be you should add commas to active class like this ng-class="{'active': mobilestatus.navActive}"

Comment: Thx for the suggestion in edit. I tried this and what happens is the function logs "the status is true" but then the element is not clickable after that. I can only click it once. Nothing happens when I click it again.

Comment: I keep getting the same behaviour. Click works first time, then it's unreactive, unclickable.

Comment: try to repeat it on plunker

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/aEvDR7A0bWoTbJoQPkoQ?p=preview) solution:

```
<div class="nav_mobile" ng-click="mobilestatus.navActive = !mobilestatus.navActive">
    <a href="" class="gradient-menu">Test- {{mobilestatus.navActive}}</a>
  </div>

  <nav>
    <ul ng-class="{'active': mobilestatus.navActive, 'inactive': mobilestatus.navActive}">
      <li><a ui-sref="about" ng-click="mobilestatus.navActive = !mobilestatus.navActive">About</a></li>
      <li><a ui-sref="contact" ng-click="mobilestatus.navActive = !mobilestatus.navActive">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```